# Is it correct to simplify modulo math with geometric progressions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

I'm not sure how much background is going to be needed so I'll just lay it out up front anyway. I am working in the finite field $GF(2^4)$ over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, that is all calculations are modulo $2$.

Since $GF(2^4)$ has a basis of $16$ elements $\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,...,\alpha^{14}\}$

where $\alpha$ is a root of the primitive polynomial $X^4=X+1$

My word length is $4$-bits and I have created a variable, I'll call it $X$, to represent the four bits in Zech's logarithmic scale.

So for instance $X^0 = 0001$, $X^2 = 0100$, and $X^{14} = 1001$ with $X^{15} = X^0 = 0001$.

And here is an example I found of the table I created :
[Table of Zech's logarithms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YQ5t.png)

I get to the point where I am trying to do something like this:

$1 + X + X^2 + X^4 + X^5 + X^6 + X^7 + X^9 + X^{10} + X^{11} + X^{12} + X^{13} + X^{14}$

Would it be correct to summarize the entire thing as a geometric progression, since they equal $0$ in binary, by adding in, two of the missing terms?

$(1 + X^{15})/(1 + X) + ( X^3 + X^8 ) = ( X^3 + X^8 )$

Yes, I understand that I can just plug and chug to get the answer but I am not sure on a fundamental level if this is correct or if I just happened to get lucky.

**Edit**, to try and add a little more clarification.

I am working in a finite field where $q$ is equal to $2$. I am creating messages with this field. The message has $15$-bits in total with $4$ redundancy bits.

I created a table for the $4$-bit codes. Then I used a primitive polynomial to get my $X$ variable. This is so you can work with the binary codes in log and it makes it much easier.  [Wikipedia: Primitive Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory))

Now I can use this $X$ variable to create a matrix and do more things from there. 
All math is done modulo $2$, even though the $X$ variable is mod $15$ it still represents binary so $2X$ would be $0$ and $-X=X$.

Comment: I do not completely understand your post. what is the value of X ? because for me $X^2=\overline{0100}=4$ leads to $X=2$ but then I don't get $X^{14}$ ? Also what it is you are calculating modulo $3$, is it the $1+X...+X^{14}$ expression ?

Comment: Also I get the feeling you want $(X^{15}-1)/(X-1)$ instead, right ?

Comment: @zwim X is a variable that represents the 4-bit binary value. When calculating the X terms I had to use the primitive polynomial X^4 = X + 1 to fill in the rest of the values. Also, subtraction and addition are the same thing in binary so I always put addition.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to put more details, because I do not understand. If you have 4-bits you are working modulo $16$ so addition and substractions are not the same (they are modulo $2$ but not modulo $16$). Then where does the $X^4=X+1$ comes from ? This is maybe logic to you, but for an external viewer, all this makes no sense so far.

Comment: @zwim Hopefully that edit helped explain it a little better.

Comment: Your first paragraph already makes my head hurt. It looks like it ought to make sense, but it really doesn't. 'Modulo 3': OK, you have a field with 3 elements. 'Word length is 4 bits': What?  'In log scale': I have no idea what this means.

Comment: @TonyK I put a link to a copy of the table I am using. If that looks familiar and you could way in on the question thanks.

Comment: I have edited the post, is it what you meant ? I have a question though, you take a message of $15$-bits and convert it in the log basis to $X$ is that it ? Or is it $X=\alpha$ ?

Comment: @zwim Yes. Thank you, I am still trying to learn the correct terminology and usage. For your question, in this instance my total number of bits is 15, the information is 12 bits and the redundant portion is 3 bits. X is alpha, i just don't know how to make those symbols.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By regrouping terms to make appear $X^n(X^4+X+1)=0$

$\begin{array}{l}
f(X)=(1+X+X^4)+X^2+(X^5+X^6+X^{9})+(X^7+X^8+X^{11})-X^8+X^{10}+(X^{12}+X^{13}+X)-X+X^{14} \\
=X^2+X^8+X^{10}+X+X^{14} \\
=(X^{13}+X^{14}+X^2)+(X^9+X^{10}-X^{13})-X^9+X^8+X \\
=(X^9+X)+X^8\\
=(XX^4X^4+X)+X^8 \\
=(X(X+1)^2+X)+X^8 \\
=(X(X^2+1)+X)+X^8 \\
=(X^3+2X)+X^8 \\
=X^3+X^8
\end{array}$

So by calculating this way it is correct.

Now if you fear about $(1+X^{15})/(1+X)$ because of the division, you can in any case multiply by $(1+X)$, till there nothing forbidden.

You also get $(f(X)+X^3+X^8)(1+X)=(1+X^{15})$ by standard calculation in any abelian group.

Now in your group since $1+X^{15}=2\equiv 0\pmod 2$ you'll find $(f(x)+X^3+X^8)(1+X)\equiv 0\pmod 2$

Now we multiply by $X^{11}$ to get $(1+X)X^{11}=X^4X^{11}=X^{15}=1\pmod 2$

Which gives $f(X)+X^3+X^8\equiv 0\pmod 2$ as expected.

So the fact that you can consider $f(X)$ as a geometric sum is because $(1+X)$ is inversible mod $2$, so this is totally justified to operate like this.

Comment: All the math I'm references is done XOR-wise. It seems like you know what I'm working on, but in case anyone else stumbles across this. Thanks zwim. Very helpful. This answer also explains why the geometric progression technique wasn't really helpful when I got to q values greater than 2.